# avoid scrolling to top after re-rendering

Tags: vue.js

Why Vuejs scrolls to top of the page after re-rendering a component . It makes it feel like refreshing the page. How may I prevent this scrolling and having the page fixed in it's position

Imaging after clicking on some part it is going to re-render it's component

Here is the piece of code where I do the update , then scrolling to top happens

```
methods: {
        updateData(data) {
            let updatedCategory = data.category;
            updatedCategory = new Category(updatedCategory);
            updatedCategory.isDefault = 1;

            for (let cat in this.categories){
                if(this.categories[cat].id === updatedCategory.id){
                    Vue.set(this.categories,cat, updatedCategory);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: this should not be happening, since only the required parts are re-rendered and this should happen quite efficiently. we need sample code or any way of reproducing. I don't like the hacky fix, suggested by steven.

Comment: @oshell I provided the code in the question

Answer (score 4):

- Discover what element has the scroll bar.
- Before updating your data, capture the `ele.scrollTop`.
- Update your data.
- In a `nextTick`, restore the element's `scrollTop`.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

Comment: What an answer! Thank you so much, of all the information this is the exact solution!